# I ran “sudo rm -rf /*” and now my PC won't boot

Tags: sudo, rm, zorin

I ran

```
sudo rm -rf /*
```

on Zorin OS because my friend dared me to and now I can't even boot to my motherboard BIOS. How should I go about fixing this? Or am I hopelessly doomed?

I have tried power cycling many times with no luck. I have tried booting to GParted. I've even removed all my drives with no success. Everything I try won't work.

Comment: Sounds like your friend owes you a new PC

Comment: Make and model of computer and motherboard please. In your question

Comment: It shouldn't stop you from getting into your BIOS but unless you have a backup, there's nothing that you can do to restore your system. I would recommend doing research before you run commands with which you aren't familiar because someone told you to.

Comment: It might boot off a Live CD, if that order happens to be configured, or the BIOS lets you select that option. If he "dared" you, exactly what outcome did you expect ? How about if he dared you to jump off a roof ?

Comment: In some circumstances [it is possible](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2402) for such command to really brick *some* hardware. Without knowing what your hardware is we cannot tell if this may have happened to you.

Comment: Yea you should be able to get to the bios, you killed your filesystem this usually doesn't mean your mobo is dead, although as one of the commenters suggested, depending on your hardware you could have torched a mobo with a poor efi implementation. If you've got a USB stick you can boot from, there are tools that might be able to help you recover your data, check out extundelete (it was the first thing I found on google). Describing exactly what you're seeing when you power on the machine may help troubleshoot.

Comment: One important lesson to learn here is: Never just run a command if you don't understand what it does - and that includes answers on sites like these - don't just copy/paste :)#

Comment: You may have to change your PC… and perhaps your friends… who does it boot without the erased disk ?

Comment: You actually ran this?

Answer (score 7):

The make and model of your motherboard would have been essential for trying to figure this out remotely, but if your system is less than 10 years old, chances are very high that it uses UEFI firmware instead of traditional BIOS.

When UEFI was introduced to the PC world, the first implementations of it were inevitably somewhat buggy, as a lot of old well-known mostly-16bit BIOS code was replaced with new 32- or 64-bit UEFI firmware code. Your problem sounds very much like a known issue with certain early UEFI firmwares on PCs.

Unlike a classic BIOS, the UEFI has a *standardized* way to store configuration settings that can also be accessible from within the running operating system: the NVRAM variables. So it would make sense for firmware developers to use that to also store the "BIOS settings".

But the fact that the settings storage is accessible from the OS means the OS can also delete or corrupt the "BIOS settings" unless the firmware author has placed protections against that and/or prepared a recovery routine if important settings are lost. Unfortunately, the firmware authors realized this only when the early implementations without sufficient protection/robustness were starting to get bricked.

Since Linux provides access to the UEFI NVRAM variables (for root only) in the form of an `efivarfs` filesystem located at `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`, this unfortunately means a `rm -rf /` run as root may also destroy UEFI NVRAM variables. The same thing is possible on Windows too, but requires specific PowerShell commands.

Usually desktop motherboards include some means of resetting the NVRAM memory (originally known as CMOS with BIOS): it could be a pair of solder blobs you temporarily connect by touching them with a screwdriver or some other metal object, a jumper, or even a small button on the motherboard.

This should reset the NVRAM to factory defaults, hopefully including resetting any removed/corrupted UEFI NVRAM variables that were required for system functionality.

But if the system can be bricked by just deleting/corrupting UEFI NVRAM variables, that is definitely a firmware bug. If you can get it back working again, look for system firmware updates ("BIOS updates") from the motherboard vendor.

If the NVRAM is reset to factory defaults, you'll also need to restore at least the UEFI boot variable for your OS. This is a new kind of problem that was necessarily introduced with UEFI and its new way of handling the boot settings.

It seems to me that the some PC hardware vendors have concentrated on making UEFI boot settings as similar to use as the old BIOS as possible, instead of providing a good interface for recovering from situations like this.

Poor handling of corrupted NVRAM could actually have the same effect as a planned obsolescence feature: if the NVRAM is implemented in the style of classic CMOS memory, as battery-backed up memory within the real-time clock chip, then once the battery runs down, it might cause the NVRAM to be corrupted and thus cause the system to be bricked in much the same way.

Comment: Was not aware of this, I am now happy that my computer boots in legacy BIOS mode and not UEFI :). This is very dangerous - shouldn't `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` filesystem be mounted read-only by default to protect from such incidents? The fact that it's available only for root doen't seem to be adequate level of protection.

Comment: @raj Kernels released after mid-2016 already have added protection, by presenting all `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` content except those variables whose purpose is positively known with the "immutable" bit set (`chattr +i`) by default. The OP just did not specify any versions so I had to describe the worst-case scenario.

Comment: One more thing I am wondering about. What if you just format the whole disk/delete all partitions (including EFI partition)? Will the computer also be unable to boot in that case (so you will be unable to install the OS)? Or if the disk fails and you replace it with a new one?

Comment: @raj Simply wiping/replacing the system disk should not cause problems, unless the firmware is egregiously buggy. And as I said, even if the UEFI variables have been corrupted, a CMOS/NVRAM reset is likely to fix it. On desktop motherboards this is usually simple, but on laptops it might be trickier, since laptops' firmware settings (including but not limited to firmware passwords) may be intentionally harder to reset to make laptop theft unprofitable.